# Set defaultViewDate in DateTimePicker , Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to set the View date, such that, when I select `DateTimePicker`, to choose dates, a default date would have been selected but it won't set the "value" of div, unless user itself select some date.

I tried using `defaultDate` parameter, but it does not defined my purpose as it sets the value too.

Here is a sub-part of code, where I want to define the parameter.

```
$("#registration-arrival-datepicker").datetimepicker({
    pickTime: true,
    useCurrent: false,
    minuteStepping: 15,
    sideBySide: true,
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
    // defaultDate :   $("#registration-arrival-datepicker").attr('start_date')
});
```

Here instead of `defaultDate`, I want some parameter which would directly take my calendar to a particular date, but not set the value unless user select it.

Also, `setDate` won't work as it sets the value too.

```
$('#registration-arrival-datepicker').data("DateTimePicker").setDate("2016-04-10");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @daredevil , is it fine now ??

Comment: you should add some code to review.. it increases your chances in getting a response.

Comment: Which DateTimePicker/DatePicker are you using? You've tagged the question with four different ones, and the answer will depend on which you are actually using.

Comment: Oh , does it vary in two APIs ?? Anyways it's `DateTimePicker`

Comment: Isn't there any one, who could give solution to my problem?? :/

Answer (score 0):

```
    var default_date= new Date();
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", default_date);
```

For Datetimepicker

```
  var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();

$('#startdatetime-from').datetimepicker({
    language: 'en',
    format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'
});
$("#startdatetime-from").data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(new Date(year, month, day, 00, 01));
```

Comment: No it's not working, See my code above , though I tried defining `localDate` parameter into that dict,  but it also didn't work